# How to show beacon notification only once a day in Swift?

Tags: swift, beacon

My beacon notification fires at any time when the beacon signal is detected. How can I limit this to receive notification only once a day?

I implemented a date check, but this didn't help. The if/else check works fine, but beacon notifications are fired disregarding this check

Any suggestion for a workaround is highly appreciated!

Here my code snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 10
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let currentDate = "\(year)\(month)\(day)"
        var savedDate = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedDate") ?? "12345"

        print(currentDate)
        print(savedDate)

        if (savedDate == currentDate){
            print("same date - no action")
        } else {
            savedDate = currentDate
            UserDefaults.standard.set(savedDate, forKey: "savedDate")
            print(savedDate + " execute program")

            let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "13D9F4C7-A68D-46F4-8D35-4BA7F64BC417")!, identifier: "estimote")
            beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
            beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = false

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = " Daily beacon check! "
            content.subtitle = "Receive a new info every day!"
            content.body = "ONLY ONCE A DAY WE SUPPLY INFO!"
            content.sound = .default
            content.badge = 1

            let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: beaconRegion, repeats: true)
            let identifier = "estimote"
            let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            })

            self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)

        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty straightforward debugging issue.  You did the right thing by adding two debug statements where I see `print(currentDate)` and `print(savedDate)`.  What do these print out?  The answer to this should give you the answer to why your program isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting

```
let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: beaconRegion, repeats: true)
let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

You are basically telling the program to go off and automatically deliver a notification when the beaconRegion condition is met. That is comfortable in case you always want the notification and let the system handle it for you. But you have no possibility to intervene at that point as it runs automatically.

What you can do is handle the notifications manually and check if you should send the notification each time the beacon is detected. Use the `locationManager(didRangeBeacons beacons:in region:)` delegate function for that:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup beacon tracking once
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 10
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "13D9F4C7-A68D-46F4-8D35-4BA7F64BC417")!, identifier: "estimote")
    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = false

    // Start looking for beacons
    self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}

// Handle beacons in range
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
    let nowString = formatter.string(from: now)

    // Check if notified ever (lastTime != nil) and if notified today
    if let lastTime = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedDate"), lastTime == nowString {
        // Already notified today, skip
        print("same date - no action")
        return
    }

    // Your notification code
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = " Daily beacon check! "
    content.subtitle = "Receive a new info every day!"
    content.body = "ONLY ONCE A DAY WE SUPPLY INFO!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = 1

    let identifier = "estimote"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: nil)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
          print("Error showing notification: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
          print("Notification shown")
        }
    })

    UserDefaults.standard.set(nowString, forKey: "savedDate")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanation!

Comment: First run -> lastTime != nowString: print("Notification shown") pops up but beacon sends no message, thereafter code runs several times through the if-statement and prints ("same date - no action"). How to get this fixed? Many thanks!

Comment: If the completion handler runs, up to that point everything should be fine. Check the contents of the `error` variable in the completion handler `if error != nil { print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")  }`

Comment: Hi Benno, many thanks for your help and support. Running the code for the first time shows the following in the log: Notification shown
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
As the first run sets the lastTate to nowString no notification is shown even if lastTime is different from nowString. Thereafter "same date - no action" is printed out several times. Completion handler shows no error. Do you have a clue how to solve the issue?? Many thanks and best regards!

Comment: You wanted the notification to show once a day right? The notification is sent the first time for that date and the day (e.g. 20180930) is saved to the user defaults. The next time the beacon comes in range the lastTime is loaded (`let lastTime = UserDefaults...` and compared to the current day. If it’s still the same day (`lastTime == nowString`) the notification is skipped. The next day lastTime `20180930` is not equal to nowString `20181001` and the lower part of the code is run and the notification is sent again. Was this not what you wanted?

Comment: Running the code for the first time no beacon notification is triggered andthe console output looks like that: Notification shown
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action
same date - no action

Comment: Once the beacon notification is actually delivered the saved date should be updated. How to achieve this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The `Notification shown` log tells you the notification code has been run without errors. 
If the notification still does not show up there is another error in your setup. 
Did you [request the necessary permission to show notifications?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)
Try to run your notification code in viewDidLoad() and see if a notification appears (without the beacon code)

Comment: Okay, a quick search showed the cause of the error is that notifications don't show when your [app is in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177103/local-notification-is-not-displayed-in-ios-10).
So you should show your own kind of notification when your app is visible. When your app is in the background when the notification is triggered, it will be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply!! Permission is ok. When app is installed for the first time icon badge = 1(but no notification is displayed , than app opens. Upon closing  badge disappears. Beacon signal with app is in the background triggers no message. As trigger is nil  how to obtain a notification?

Comment: Trigger is set to `nil` to invoke a notification right away (not at a specified time). I'm guessing you are trying to start the app with either a previously set value in `lastTime` or the notification code is already called before you put your app in background.
Try to comment out the `if let lastTime ...` part to check if your notification spawns in background. 
From here it is more a debugging / design problem, that I can't help you further with and that doesn't belong in this question on Stackoverflow. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input - finally problem solved!!